# How to find the number of connected components of a graph by using its 16x16 adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, connectedness, trees

Good day,

I have this exercice that provides me with the 16x16 matrix of adjacency of a graph and it asks me to find the number of connected components of the graph and I need to give a spanning tree for each of these components. I have noticed that in a similar question someone suggested the Laplacian matrix, but I don't see how that would work (I am not particularly good in math). I attached the matrix in cause in case you ever need it. Thank you in advance for answering my question[image]

Comment: Why don't you just draw the graph? 16 vertices is not that much at all!

Comment: I know it's not, it's actually pretty accetable. But I am only thinking that if this was a really huge graph, I wouldn't be able to apply the same solution, and I tend to think that with math, there is always a general way to do it. I am looking for an alternative not out of lazyness, but because I am constantly seeking general rules and means to acheive certain results. Thank you for your proposition, though!

Comment: Here's the method I use for solving this currently (for this example):

1. I look at the first row of the matrix and I see that 1 is adjacent to 5 and 10;
2. I look at rows 5 and 10, I see that 5 is adjacent to 1 and 10 and 10 is adjacent to 1, 5, 11 and 16;
3. I look at 11 and it is adjacent to 10 and 16;
4. I look at 16 and it is adjacent to 11 and 10; this is where it ends and where we start going backwords so I know that there is a connected component that is 1-5-10-11-16;
5. You repeat for another node that is not mentioned.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, then you could manually apply any algorithm that finds connected components, like DFS, and then use any algorithm that finds a spanning tree, like DFS. In fact these two can be combined. But I doubt you would like to do this manually for larger graphs and for smaller it's really better to just draw.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, @dtldarek, thanks for your help.